# Question about the proof to a corollary of Whitney Embedding Theorem from John Lee

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have some questions about the proof of a Corollary to the Whitney Embedding Theorem from John Lee's Smooth Manifolds.

In the proof below, why is the product map $G=f\times F$ a smooth embedding? I can see that it is an injective smooth immersion since $F$ is, but how can I show that this is also a topological embedding, i.e. a hoemomorphism onto its image $G(M)\subset \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ in the subspace topology?

Also, how can I show that if a vector $v_{N+2n+1}$ is arbitrarily close to $e_{N+2n+1}=(0,\dots,0,1)$ then the orthogonal projection map $\pi_{v_{N+2n+1}}$ is arbitrarily close to $\pi_{e_{N+2n+1}}$?

I would greatly appreciate any help with these questions.

[image]

Comment: A continuous injective map $f$  from a compact metric space $K$ is an homeomorphism onto its image. Also the orthogonal projection is continuous therefore uniformely continuous on this compact set.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you so they both relied on compactness. I was wondering where the assumption of compactness is used here.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician If I am not wrong, it doesn't rely on compactness.
If $f:K\to L$ is smooth, then $(id,f):K\to K\times L, k\mapsto(k,f(k))$ is a smooth embedding. So, in your case, $(id,f):M\to R^N$ is a smooth embedding.
If $F_i:K_i\to L_i$ is a smooth embedding, for $i=1,2$, their product $F_1\times F_2:K_1\times K_2\to L_1\times L_2$ is a smooth embedding. So, in your case, $F\times id:M\times R^N\to R^{N+2n+1}$ is a smooth embedding.
Compositions of smooth embeddings are smooth embeddings, so $F\times f=(F\times id)\circ(\text{id},f):M\times R^N\to R^{N+2n+1}$ is a smooth embedding

Answer (score 0):

A bit late and nothing that hasn’t been said in the comments but maybe a worthwhile thought due to its explicitness:

The map $G=f\times F: M\to \mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ is a homeomorphism as the composition of the projection $\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ and the inverse map $F^{-1}:F(M)\to M$ induces the inverse map of $G$ and is continuous. So indeed, this part of the proof does not depend on the compactness of $M$.

The second part relies on compactness to give a uniform approximation.